# How to concatenate the array in a sub-schema of a schema using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models one is called `User` and the other `Item`. An array of items is assigned to each User (each user has 5 items). Through each user's session, the user will answer some questions and the answers will be stored in an array. Here is the Models:

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    answers: {
        type: Array,
    },
});
//Create the User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  items: [ItemSchema],
});

UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  this.items = [];
  this.items.push({
    title: "Item 1",
    answers: ["", "", ""]
  });
  this.items.push({
    title: "Item 2",
    answers: ["", "", ""]
  });
  this.items.push({
    title: "Item 3",
    answers: ["", "", ""]
  });
  this.items.push({
        title: "Item 4",
        answers: ["", "", ""]
      });
  this.items.push({
        title: "Item 5",
        answers: ["", "", ""]
      });
  next();
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

My question is if 20 Users has logged in and answered the questions, how I can concatenate all of the answers together in an array. So as a response I'll have the following :

```
[
    {
        "title": "Item 1",
        "allAnswers":["user1-answer1","user1-answer2","user1-answer3","user2-answer2","user2-answer2",...]
    },
    {
        "title": "Item 2",
        "allAnswers":["user1-answer1","user1-answer2","user1-answer3","user2-answer2","user2-answer2",...]
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [static method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) on `UserSchema` to access all users and concatenate the answers in a array.

as follows

```
UserSchema.statics.ItemsToArray = function(){
    let users = this.Find()
    // Further actions on Users and their responses
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually my main problem is to take a specific field(in my case "answers") out of an array sub-shema of schema. In the function you defined I can define  let items = users.distinct("items"); but rather than that I don't know how to push all the answers related to title: "Item 1" in one array and all the answers related to title: "Item 2" in another one etc...